# Problems in Google Chart API: Bar Chart Legend text duplicated

Tags: google-visualization

I have a question about Google Chart API.

I'm working on Bar Chart to show a stacked bar graph.

Here's a problem that legend texts are duplicated as shown in the image below.

I set an option like this.

```
    var options = {
        isStacked: true,
        legend: {position:'bottom'},
        backgroundColor: {fill:'#f5f5f5'},
        width: 350,
        colors:['#32bb32','#06abe8','#ffcb05','#f15a22']
    };
```

Do you have any idea?

[image]

Comment: I cannot recreate your problem. When they overlap for me, it has an arrow leading to the other entries. Go here: 
http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?type=visualization#bar_chart
and add these to the options:
`           {title:"Yearly Coffee Consumption by Country",
            width:350, height:400,
            vAxis: {title: "Year"},
            hAxis: {title: "Cups"},
            legend: {position: "bottom"},}`

Answer (score 0):

Messing about with google charts can get a bit, well, messy. A terrible solution that happens to get the job done is to insert an excessive number of white spaces after your label, then increase the font size under text style like so:

`legend: { position: 'bottom', alignment: 'center', textStyle: { fontSize: 15,}},`

This is a quick and dirty solution to annoying overlapping in the legend. 
With google charts, nearly all problems can be fixed using custom templates, but this solution will hold if you just want to wash your hands of the problem and move on.